# Where's my money?

Tags: combinatorics

A rich man is on the verge of dying. He has unlimited amount of money and intends to distribute some of it among his $n$ relatives with the following conditions :-

1. Total money to be distributed must be a positive multiple of $j$.
2. No relative gets more than $mj-1$ dollars. (A relative may not get money)

Find total number of ways in which the rich man can distribute the money.

Take $n=6, j=5,$ and $m=3$

Comment: No relative gets more than 14 dollars? He must really *love* his relatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that only whole dollars can be given,

> There are $mj$ possibilities for the first $n-1$ relatives, and $m$ for the last one to make the total divisible by $j$. The answer is $m^nj^{n-1}$. For the given values, this is $2278125$ ways.